# Software to split one display into two or more virtual screens?

Tags: osx, display

First: this is going to sound weird at first. I might be the only person that wants this.

---

I've used two-screen setups every now and then, and I find that the separation between them helps me be more organized. On OS X, especially (and probably other platforms), maximizing a window causes it to become the size of the currently open display, which helps me tremendously with window resizing.

I have a rather large (external) display, and I'd like to be able to 'split' it right down the middle, turning it into two side-by-side displays as far as the OS is concerned. Is there an application that allows me to do this?

The Graphics Card is a `NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB`, if that matters.

**Note**: Perhaps a [tiling window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) be OK, although I'm really looking to be able to simulate a physical display so that I get all the benefits from that.

Comment: Yeah [I understand](https://www.quora.com/Survey-Questions/What-does-your-workstation-look-like/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt?share=1) :)

Comment: That's an awesome setup, @FranckDernoncourt. I want it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If managing half screen window maximizations is the biggest requirement there are some window snapping softwares.
Windows 7 has [snap](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snap) built in that lets you maximize windows to half the screen. I have a love hate with this one. Mostly I hate it when it snaps when I don't want it too.

OSX has [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) on the mac app store for $1.99. you can get [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) for free which also provides custom gestures. It looks like the developer extracted the snap feature out of BetterTouchTool since people got it just for the snaping feature. I just got it to test it out and so far its pretty cool. Unlike windows 7 snapping BetterSnap allows for quarter window sizing. I have a 3 monitor setup and it is working nicely on each monitor

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant. I believe he wants to use one monitor screens as two independent screens..Like having two desktops and stuff.